# Cumulus parachain (branch=release-polkadot-v1.5.0) with the pallet-contracts given this error:"StorageDepositNotEnoughFunds/BadOrigin"

Tags: pallet-contracts, cumulus, polkadot-sdk

**Rust version**:rustc 1.77.0-nightly (3d0e6bed6 2023-12-21)

**Zombienet-linux-x64 version**:1.3.87

**Polkadot SDK version**:polkadot 1.5.0-a3dc2f15f23

---

I have created a simple [Cumulus Parachain](https://github.com/blue-freedom-technologies/cumulus-parachain) based in the new Polkadot SDK [monorepo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/release-polkadot-v1.5.0/cumulus/parachain-template).

Which I am testing using a zombienet [network specification](https://github.com/blue-freedom-technologies/cumulus-parachain/blob/main/network-specification.toml).

The zombienet is created with no problem.

[image]

I am able to do transfer tokens between accounts.

[image]

But I am not able to upload a smart contract (I am using the [flipper](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/flipper) example)

From the Substrate Contracts UI

Callers account
[image]

[image]

[image]

From the Polkadot JS with the sudo command

[Alice Sudo key -local_testnet_config](https://github.com/blue-freedom-technologies/cumulus-parachain/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L163)

[Alice Sudo key -development_config](https://github.com/blue-freedom-technologies/cumulus-parachain/blob/main/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L111)

Alice tokens

[image]

Alice transaction

[image]

[image]

[image]

Probably I am missing something silly.

Nevertheless, would be nice to know why this code have this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this error the MaxHolds(The maximum number of holds that can exist on an account at any time) in the "impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime" needs to be bigger then 1.

```
impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    (...)
    type MaxHolds = ConstU32<1>;
    (...)
}
```

Cheers,